# Trouble finding the right DTFT pair

Tags: signal-processing

i have a periodic signal $x[n] = \cos (\frac{2 \pi}{10}n)$.
I found this DTFT pair:

[image]

That's the only pair for a cosine function i found.
But what is $\delta _{2\pi}$ ? Is it just a Dirac $\delta$ function for every period ?
And the $\pi$ before the brackets is just for a higher amplitude of the impulse ?

Comment: Ultimately, the $\pi$ before the brackets is a _convention_. You can change how you define the Fourier transform, but then you'd also need to change the inverse transform.

Normally, $\delta_{2\pi}$ denotes a _periodic delta function_, meaning that $\delta_{2\pi}(x) = \delta_{2\pi}(y) \Leftrightarrow x = y + 2 k \pi$ for some integer $k$. I can't really see if that should be the case here, but you should verify it.

Comment: Well, it just says calculate the periodic signal $x[n]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTFT is always $2\pi$-periodic, since changing the frequency by $2\pi$ doesn't change the phase at the integers. The cosine is a sum of two exponentials and has frequency components at $\theta_0$ and $-\theta_0$. The $\delta_{2\pi}$ function replicates these with period $2\pi$. As was already stated in the comments, the factor $\pi$ is a matter of convention; it gives the right normalization for the definition used e.g. in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTFT).